# cannot create "test" folder in android studio for robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, intellij-idea, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I want to add robolectric tests to my project in intellij.

I have tried to follow this [tutorial](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/)

but I cannot add "test" package under my main module.

In addition the "build variants" look different than  in the tutorial.

how can I fix this?

how can I add test class properly?

[image]

Comment: Which version of Android Studio and android gradle plugin do you use? Easy unit tests only supported if both is 1.1 or above. If you have already latest versions then switch to project view (your screenshots show android view) and create <module>/src/test/java folder and then the java folder should get a green color. Should be no need to change source paths.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is not the way, the good architecture is:

```
/app
    /src
        /main
             /java
                  /com.your.package
        /test
             /java
                  /com.your.package
```

and don't forget to write it in the app module build.gradle

```
android {
  sourceSets {
    main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java'] }
    test { java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java'] }
  }
}
```

Comment: given i cannot change the structure. Where should I put my tests?

Comment: ok i see, maybe try  /java/test/java/com.your.package, you will have to set the good path in sourceSets  : test { java.srcDirs = ['/test/java']

Comment: I would not do it, the issue is just default project layout is not convenient for folder creation

Comment: Great answer! Also, don't forget to 'sync project with Gradle files', the popup didn't appear so I had to trigger that manually

Answer (score 1):

You need to change Project layout from **Android** to **Project**:
[image: Current layout]

[image: Select another layout]

[image: New layout]

And now you can easily create folders from **Android Studio** UI

Answer (score 0):

I guess you had an outdated tutorial. Android Studio changed, there is no need to use Build Variants to distinguish between UnitTest and AndroidTests anymore.

Just create the TestFolders manually. e.g. `app/scr/androidTest` and put your test Files there.

Maybe just create a new Project with android Studio. The Folders for tests will be atomatically created, you'll see what i mean.

Comment: given i cannot change the structure. Where should I put my tests?